# Movie/Tv Show api (with posters) for commercial user

Tags: api, film

I am looking for a movie and tv show database with a good developer friendly api which can be used for commercial purposes (Android app).

http://www.themoviedb.org/ looked like a good options but apparently they are not allowing more commercial apps.

Right now I am leaning towards http://www.omdbapi.com/ but before I start writing all my code for it I wanted to make sure there weren't other better options. My main requirement is that they give me a url for a poster for said tv show or movie.

Comment: It is unbelievable that using OMDb API I do not violate intellectual property, don't you think? Rotten tomatoes and IMDB too has a very long Terms of Service when / how to store / use posters etc.

Answer (score 1):

[A question like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787808/is-there-any-online-free-movie-information-apis) was asked on Stack Overflow a few years ago.

Besides TheMovieDB (which was the accepted answer), and [OMDB](http://www.omdbapi.com/), which you've found,  people suggested the [Rotten Tomatoes API](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/Home), which appears to have posters, but which also looks like it's integrated into OMDB...

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at rotten tomatoes. I was really hoping to find something like thetvdb.com with great posters and banners but also with movie data.

Comment: apparently rotten tomatoes does not have TV shows API only API for Movies