# Where to Find a Downloadable Movie Database

Tags: uses-of-open-data, film

I am looking for a movie database that is either open or low cost for a project. Can somebody point me to one?

Comment: See also http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5589/movie-script-database http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2011/movie-tv-show-api-with-posters-for-commercial-user http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/589/is-there-an-open-movie-and-or-music-database-available-for-commercial-use